# How to remove an EventListener by the time of creation?

Tags: javascript, event-listener

I need a way to remove the EventListeners of an object as a queue sort of thing, where the first EventListener added is the first one in the list, or the first to be removed.

Also, if I don't know what the EventListener does (but I do know the object that is holding the EventListener)

Like if I had this set up:

```js
var btn = document.getElementById("mybtn");
// Some example listeners, some don't make sense.
btn.addEventListener("click", onClick, false);
btn.addEventListener("keydown", onKeyDown, false);
btn.addEventListener("keyup", onKeyUp, false);

function onClick(){
    alert("You clicked me!");
}

function onKeyDown(){
    console.log("Key down");
}

function onKeyUp(){
    console.log("Key up");
}
```

```html
<button id="mybtn">Do stuff! I use listeners.</button>
```

I would have three EventListners on `mybtn`. Now, how would I remove the EventListener that was first added, or get a list of the EventListeners and remove one from the list?



Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way to remove an event listener is to call [`removeEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener) and pass it the listener you want to remove as an argument.

To achieve what you want, you must maintain the list of listeners in the order you add them yourself.

Since you are dealing with listeners of different types, you'll need to track the type too.

```
function someListener(e) {}
function someOtherListener(e) {}
function someOtherListener(e) {}

var tracker = [];

btn.addEventListener("click", someListener, false);
tracker.push({ event: "click", listener: someListener });
btn.addEventListener("keydown", someOtherListener, false);
tracker.push({ event: "keydown", listener: someOtherListener });
btn.addEventListener("keyup", someOtherListener, false);
tracker.push({ event: "keyup", listener: someOtherListener });

var remove = tracker.unshift();
btn.removeEventListener( remove.event, remove.listener );
```

(NB: For a more elegant approach to the above, you could create the array and then loop over it to add the listeners.)

Comment: Thank you, this really helped :)